# Passing get Request parameters through Url to the managed bean for login validation in jsf1.2

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, get, request, url-parameters

I have a requirement where the portal application that is being developed in jsf 1.2 and spring 2.5 will be launched from within an ipad app. After the user logs into the ipad app, the user click on the portal link available and the ipad app in turn will be passing the user credentials through a get request url which i will have to validate and redirect them to home.xhtml page if the validation is successful else i will have to redirect them to error page. I have been searching in google a lot to see how this can be implemented. Finally i found that it requires a phase listener to implement this but I am not sure how this can be done or if there is any other way. Please tell me how can this be done using phase listener (if possible with an example). Also suggest me if i can use any other means to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to implement this. I am giving the solution that i used so that it might help some one else. 
I am using a servlet filter to get the parameters from the URL and then i am validating the credentials with the data stored in the DB. Then if the credentials are valid i am redirecting the user to the home page. If the credentials are invalid then i am redirecting the user to error page. Done.